# Spark replaceWhere error even after filtering df

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, delta-lake

I tested this on 10 date partitions and 3 failed. I'm completely lost on what could be the issue. dt is just a widget for local testing.

```
dbutils.widgets.text('dt', '', 'dt: yyyy-MM-dd')
# 2022-05-18

silver_df = spark.sql(f"""
    select data:id::int as id
        , data:name::string as user_name
        , substring(data:location::string, 0, 100) as country_name
        , data:updated_at::string as updated_at
        , to_date(data:updated_at::string) as dt
        , dt as processed_dt
    from bronze.{table_name}
    where dt = '{dt}'
    qualify row_number() over(partition by id order by updated_at desc) = 1
    """)

(
    silver_df
    .write
    .format('delta')
    .partitionBy('dt', 'processed_dt')
    .mode('overwrite')
    .option('replaceWhere', f"processed_dt == '{dt}'")
    .saveAsTable(f"{database}.{table_name}")
)
```

`AnalysisException: Data written out does not match replaceWhere 'processed_dt == '2022-05-18''.`

Comment: what DBR version are you using?

Comment: Hello.  Would like to see creation script of your table.  It may help.